# Virtualbox, how to make guest wallpaper transparent?

Tags: virtualbox, desktop-background

Ubuntu (16.04) host, Windows 10 guest in VirtualBox. How do you make the guest (Win10) wallpaper transparent? Running seamless mode.

I've recently gotten back into Linux. I remember doing this with my Mac, running Windows XP in seamless mode with a transparent wallpaper on the windows machine (guest)

How do I do this with Windows 10 as guest on my Ubuntu 16.04 host?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install guest additions first after that in the toolbar there is seamless mode click it and you will have seamless mode

Comment: I've done that, seamless mode work 100%. What I want to do is make the guest machine (win10) have a transparent background (wallpaper), so when it runs "on-top" of the host machine (ubuntu 16.04) , you don't see the guest background (wallpaper)

Comment: IIRC seamless mode should not show the guest wallpaper, I think that is the bug with windows 10 guest seamless mode, check this https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=78179